# Running makebst in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, custom-bib

I am trying to create a customised bibliography for LaTeX using makebst. However, when I type in `latex makebst` in my terminal, I get the following error message:

```
$ latex makebst

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.


entering extended mode


! I can't find file `makebst'.


<*> makebst
```

I have a Linux Ubuntu 18.04 (32 bit, which sometimes causes problems). I have TeXMaker and TeXStudio installed, but usually use LaTeX in Overleaf.

I am new to LaTeX and not much of a programmer (despite having a Linux), meaning that I might be making a really obvious mistake. Any ideas what is going wrong here would be much appreciated!

Comment: Check if you have `makebst.tex` installed somewhere, it is part of the `custom-bib` package (as you probably know because you tagged `custom-bib`). If you have that file then the issue is that it is not in the path where LaTeX looks for files. If you don't have it then you need to install it. How to install depends on how you installed LaTeX inself, using distribution packages (with `apt install`) or using the TeX Live installer script.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks!